# Creating Custom Symbology Patchs for ArcGIS Pro Map Legends?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, style, arcgis-pro, legend

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a custom symbology patch to be applied to a map legend in ArcGIS Pro?

I know this was possible in ArcGIS Desktop within the legend properties dialog, Items tab, style properties window.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this feature is not currently available as far as I can find at [How to Change Legend Patch Shape?](https://community.esri.com/thread/179743) However, there is a workaround.

> At least from the ESRI Help, it appears that unfortunately this is not an option.  It looks like one can only do sizing of the current patch, not change its shape.

> From the Help:
> On the Design tab, you can set the default legend patch size. In the  Settings group, you can select or input a size for Patch Width and Patch Height.

> It appears only the size of the patch at the moment can be modified,
> [Update legend patch size](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/work-with-a-legend.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_FC5D4FD43E4B46FCB5D8A54DE5E0D392)

> You can set the default legend patch size by right-clicking the legend item in the Contents pane and choosing Properties. In the Format Legend pane, you can change the size for Patch Width and Patch Height

> Also, it appears a potential work-around of importing a different patch shape from an existing mxd set up in ArcGIS Desktop is also out:
> Because the functionality of legends in ArcGIS Pro does not match the functionality available in ArcMap, legends will be converted to use settings available in ArcGIS Pro.

> [Import an existing legend](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/import-an-existing-legend.htm)

> Legends are imported with ArcMap documents. When you import an ArcMap document, maps and layouts are created separately in your project. If the layout in your ArcMap document contains a legend, it will be imported with the layout and adjusted to use the properties and settings available in ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2):

In the symbology window for that layer, you will see the different symbols for each class in that layer. Beside the symbol is a tiny drop-down arrow that will give different symbology styles for that class, similar to what what available in ArcMap. It is a feature that many people want but it is quite hidden, and oddly it is not available in any of the property windows for the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Under the [Apply a legend patch](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/symbolize-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A1F24F1750E0466E9DD56C089419ABC8) heading of the [Symbolize feature layers](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/symbolize-feature-layers.htm#) page in the Online Help it says:

> ... you can further symbolize feature layer data by changing the
> legend patch of any line or polygon feature layer. Legend patches
> change the preview shape of the symbol shown in the Symbology and
> Contents panes, as well as in layout legends.
>
> To change the shape of the layer's legend patch, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Highlight a feature layer by clicking its title in the Contents pane. The Feature Layer contextual tab appears on the ribbon.
> 2. Under Feature Layer on the Appearance tab in the Drawing group, click the Symbology button Symbology.
> 3. In the Symbology pane, on the Primary symbology tab Primary symbology, click the Update legend patch shape drop-down arrow next to
>    the symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can change the patch shape in the legend by changing the patch shape in the symbology for that layer.

Comment: Hi Kelly and welcome in the GIS community. As your answer may be used  as reference. Could you elaborate a little how you managed to create the custom symbology (and maybe show us a little example) ? that would be great thx